# Create a gradient within a polygon based on the amount of point data in each area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, point, arcgis-10.8

I have species presence points that are scattered throughout a watershed polygon, and I am trying to see how many points are within each subbasin of that watershed and then see if I can create a gradient where 0 is no points and 5 is many. If this is doable the end product will preferably be a raster layer or able to convert into a raster layer.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Spatial join the points to the polygon to get the column `Join count` which is the number of points in each polygon
2. Symbolize by Join count field:

[image]